# SVG getScreenCTM() on FireFox

Tags: svg, firefox, matrix-transform

**GOAL**

I am trying to build a signature pad in SVG. You can view
[Sample project here](https://1dollar-shop.com/canvas/).

**Description**
So far, it works in Chrome, Edge and Opera as desired but, in Firefox, getScreenCTM() doesn't account for the scale.

**Research**

I went through a bunch of documentation from bugzilla and a couple of posts here in SO such as [SVG: GetScreenCTM() for nested SVG is different in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37417075/svg-getscreenctm-for-nested-svg-is-different-in-firefox) but, still couldn't figure out how to fix my issue.

**Problem**

I've added a browse check to handle only Firefox (since all other browsers provides the desired result) which allows me to add extra code to fix the problem but, thus far, had no success. (SPSignature:416)

**Reproduce the error**

To reproduce the error, open the sample link in FireFox than, resize the box so it is at least 20% smaller as in fullscreen. You will see the mouseX/Y position change as scale changes.

I've tried to get the matrix transform from the group tag but, it returns similar result from the SVG. How do I calculate the CTM, so its result is similar/equal to Chrome?

**Code**

Source code [here](https://1dollar-shop.com/canvas/SPSignature.js) SPSignature:416

```
 _getCursorPoint(event)
{
    const svg = document.querySelector('.spsignature svg');
    let pt = svg.createSVGPoint();

    pt.x = event.clientX;
    pt.y = event.clientY;

    // firefox workaround:
    if (this._checkBrowser() === 'Firefox') {
        const matrix = this._decomposeMatrix(svg.getScreenCTM());

        let cood = { 
            x: event.layerX, 
            y: event.layerY
        };

        if (matrix.scaleX < 0.9 || matrix.scaleY < 0.9) {
            console.log('%c @todo: fix mouse position for FF on getScreenCTM().', 'background:#c00;color:#fff;padding:3px;');
        }

        return cood;
    }

    return pt.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
}
```

Comment: The other question you link to shouldn't apply here as you don't seem to be using nested `<svg>` elements.  Frankly it's going to be hard for anyone to help you because you haven't provided any sample code.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates how you are using `getScreenCTM()` and that it is giving bad results in Firefox.

Comment: @Paul LeBeau I've provided the project sample. As far as code goes, it can be seem on the project's sample source code (https://1dollar-shop.com/canvas/SPSignature.js)

Comment: There is a reason why Stack Overflow has a rule that you should provide a [mcve]. Most people here don't have the time to trawl through large code files, debugging it for you. You can increase your chances by making it easy for them to see the problem.

Comment: @Robert Longson - I've tried to change as suggested. Chrome didn't complain about it and worked as before but, FF threw an error on createSVGPoint. But, it gave me the idea of using the svg scale value to try to fix the mouseXY points.

Comment: **link to the sample project is a 404**

Answer (score -1):

To "fix" the mouse XY problem on FF, I've used the root scale value to allow for the calculation of the cursor XY position.

The scale can be retrieved from the matrix based on https://gist.github.com/2052247.

Also, in FF, I've used the `event.layerX` and `event.layerY` instead of `event.clientX` and `event.clientY` for the initial mouse coordinate values.

So, instead of using `matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse())` to return the calculated XY relative to the SVG, I've used the scale and layerXY to calculate the right XY position.

Comment: I think the real solution is much easier than that.

Comment: This is what worked for me. I also think there is a better way to fix FF CTM but, all I got thus far was ppl criticizing about the lack of minimal reproducible example so, just took the time to live my working solution for the next guy.

Comment: We're not criticizing, we're asking so that we can help you properly.

Comment: This is a known issue in Firefox. It has allegedly been fixed a number of times over the last decade, but at the time of writing is currently broken. See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1610093